# Execute the last thread in threadloop

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am implementing a comic reader in C# 4.0, and browsing from one image
to the next takes some time because of some processes I implemented.

Therefore, I implemented it in such a way that the UI thread will show
first the unprocessed image whilst the background thread is processing
the image and will later replace the unprocessed image.

It all works fine but now, some users will crazily like to click next
image continusly and this causes the background worker to processes
all those clicks and display all the images.

WHAT I WANT: if a user clicks multiple times, I want the background
worker to process the last thread only.

WHAT I HAVE DONE: Now, I have implemented a function to check the
number of active threads, if the active threads is greater than 1,
background thread will not process but returns the previous image(THAT
IS NOT GOOD, because the unprocessed image will be one index ahead)

If you have idea please explain to me like a beginner!

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(this.CurrImage);

           if (!shutdown)
          {
            process_updateThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(process_update));
            process_updateThread.Start();
          }

    pictureBox1.Image = b; //image will be replaced by worker thread image 
    pictureBox1.Location = ImageEdit.CalculateLocationImage(b);
    SetBackColor(b);
    ShowPageCount();
    updateNavButtons(); 
}


void StopThread()
{
    if(((IEnumerable)System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads).OfType<System.Diagnostics.ProcessThread>()
        .Where(t => t.ThreadState == System.Diagnostics.ThreadState.Running).Count() > 1) 
    shutdown = true;
    else shutdown = false;
}
```

Comment: 1. Can you estimate the time taken for the process update to complete? If yes, then you can have a timer for that time and allow the user click to create new thread only after the past thread is completed. 2. Set a flag when the Thread is completed. Check the flag value, to enable user to create another new thread. This way you allow user to create thread one by one, irrespective of how many clicks. Rather than all the threads at a time.

Comment: Thanks Brian for editing and responding to my question. The process takes 2 seconds on average to complete. I think I will try this one first. My head is all mixed up at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your long running process is process_update.

You must stop all running process_updates before running the next one. But **DON'T USE BOOLEAN VARIABLE TO DO THAT**!!! You must use synchronizing objects. Most likely it should be ManualResetEvent.

**UPDATE:**

This very simple example can give you an idea of multithreading and thread management

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;


namespace WindowsFormsExamples
{
    public partial class OnlyOneThread : Form
    {
        List<ManualResetEvent> threadStopEvents;    //This will hold stop events for running threads

        public OnlyOneThread()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            threadStopEvents = new List<ManualResetEvent>();
        }

        private void runThreadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ManualResetEvent evt = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            ParameterizedThreadStart ts = new ParameterizedThreadStart(this.ThreadFunc);
            Thread t = new Thread(ts);
            t.Start(evt);
        }

        private delegate void UptadeThreadCountDelegate();   //This delegate is used by Invoke method
        private void UpdateThreadCount()
        {
            threadcountLbl.Text = threadStopEvents.Count.ToString();
        }

        protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnClosed(e);
            //We must stop threads if they are still running

            lock (threadStopEvents)  // locking prevents simultaneous list access
            {
                foreach (ManualResetEvent evt in threadStopEvents)
                {
                    evt.Set(); //signal all events
                }
            }
        }


        //This is thread function
        private void ThreadFunc(Object obj)
        {
            ManualResetEvent stopEvent = obj as ManualResetEvent; //cast an object that was passed by Thread.Start()

            lock (threadStopEvents) // locking prevents simultaneous list access
            {
                foreach (ManualResetEvent evt in threadStopEvents)
                {
                    evt.Set(); //signal all events for all other threads to stop
                }

                threadStopEvents.Add(stopEvent);  //Put our event on list
            }

            if (this.IsHandleCreated) // This is necessary for invocation
                this.Invoke(new UptadeThreadCountDelegate(this.UpdateThreadCount));  //Invoke counter update

            for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) // this will run about 1 minute
            {
                if (stopEvent.WaitOne(0)) // Tests stopEvent and continues
                {
                    //Stop signaled!!! exit!
                    break;
                }

                Thread.Sleep(1000); //Sleep 1 second
            }
            lock (threadStopEvents) // locking prevents simultaneous list access
            {
                threadStopEvents.Remove(stopEvent); //remove stop event from list
            }
            if (this.IsHandleCreated) // This is necessary for invocation
                this.Invoke(new UptadeThreadCountDelegate(this.UpdateThreadCount));  //Invoke counter update
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to run this example you must create WindowsForms project and add Button and label on the form, then use this code to bind to those controls. Note an invocation of forms method. This is necessary when don from non-GUI threads.

Comment: Thanks David, sounds interesting can you give me an example. process_update is my long running process.

Answer (score 0):

I can not see an easy solution to this problem... Multithreading is never easy. Personally, I would propose following (a sort of deviation of the producer/consumer situation):

- First have a general counter which signifies the currently to be rendered image (can be a simple int which is incremented for each button pressed)

An ImageMonitor which is nicely locked and has a methods to:

- add an image to be rendered (with the current counter) -> this happens for each button pressed
- retrieve the image which should be rendered (including the counter of the image)
- Process a rendered image

Now we need a continously working Background thread which loops and in every iteration checks the ImageMonitor for the newest image to process, processes the image and returns it back to the ImageMonitor (including the counter)

When the ImageMonitor gets a rendered image from the background renderer, then it can check if the image has the correct counter value, if so then it can swap the current image with the rendered image

This solution is obviously a little complicated. However, it should work. I'm interested in other (easier) solutions.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, Daniel..I will try it but it looks complicated for my level and I believe it might add more time to browse an image

Comment: True, its not exactly simple... maybe one of the other answers can show a better solution